# Custom component topbar button event RNN v2

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

I have a custom component 'MenuButton' in my RNNv2 topbar. I want openMenu() to run when this button is clicked, but this doesn't happen. My typescript linting tells me `Property openMenu does not exist on typeof Home`. Why is this?

```
 class Home extends React.PureComponent<Props, State> {
    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        Navigation.events().bindComponent(this);
    }

    closeMenu = () => {
        this._drawer.close();
    };
    openMenu = () => {
        this._drawer.open();
    };
    static options(passProps) {
        return {
            topBar: {
                rightButtons: [
                    {
                        component: {
                            name: 'MenuButton',
                            passProps: {
                                onClick: () => this.openMenu(),
                            },
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
              ...
        );
    }
}
```

Reference I got my `passProps` code from: https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/3648

Comment: it is because options is a static method?

Comment: Can you include `Props` interface definition?

Answer (score 0):

`openMenu` is a method of instance, while `static options(passProps)` is a static obliviously.

Your `onClick` is defined via arrow function like `() => this.openMenu()` which means it is forced to use static context.

Although https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/3648#issuecomment-408680892 suggests arrow function, I do not believe it works so. 
You have to provide the instance of Home component to the `MenuButton` somehow.

The most dirty hack is following:

```
let homeInstance: Home | undefined;

class Home extends React.PureComponent<Props, State> {
    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        Navigation.events().bindComponent(this);
        homeInstance = this;
    }

    closeMenu = () => {
        this._drawer.close();
    };
    openMenu = () => {
        this._drawer.open();
    };
    static options(passProps) {
        return {
            topBar: {
                rightButtons: [
                    {
                        component: {
                            name: 'MenuButton',
                            passProps: {
                                onClick: () => { 
                                   if(homeInstance) {
                                      homeInstance.openMenu()
                                   } else {
                                      console.warn("homeInstance is not initialised");
                                   }
                                },
                            },
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
              ...
        );
    }
}
```

We have a kind of singleton here, so it is not a perfect solution. I would try to improve it using React.Context